# What permissions (Profile) are required to run or schedule Batch Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

In Salesforce, there are some batch jobs that are manually run by scheduling the job from a Visualforce page with a custom controller that schedules a batch job. This process is necessary because the User running the job provides a specific set of Salesforce Account IDs for the batch. The User that schedules this batch job has administrator privileges. We are considering giving this User a non-administrator profile for security reasons.

My question is, what permissions on the Profile are required to run (`Database.executeBatch`) or schedule Batch Apex (run a class that implements `Schedulable`)?

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for my salesforce stack exchange proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce

Not exactly code, but it is definitely part of salesforce development!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any particular permissions that are required. The user will need access to the records that go in the batch.

Comment: A contact on Twitter mentioned that the "Author Apex" permission is required? Are you able to run or schedule batches without that permission?

Comment: authoring apex means creating/editing apex classes and triggers. Executing is completely different.

Comment: I'm about to test it, but what you say makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: After testing thoroughly, I found that permissions to view the Visualforce page are required, as well as access to the edit the records, as you mentioned. Other than that, you're correct that there are no additional permissions required. I was confused by checking the Schedule Apex (accessible from viewing Classes), Apex Jobs, Scheduled Jobs pages. To view those, or schedule a batch manually, the User would need the Profile permission: `Modify All Data`.